# Email Alert not Sending

Tags: process-builder, email-template

I have an email alert I want to send only when a Lead is created by user 'Request for Information Guest User'. The email should be sent to the create Lead's email listed in the 'Email' line -  Is there a reason, with my current settings, why the email will not be sent?

Here are my Email Alert Settings:
[image]

Here are my Process Builder flow settings:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything was going straight to Spam. I will adjust.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144409)

Comment: @Himanshu - I do see this as an answer to my initial quesiton.  The settings were accurate within SalesForce, and the emails were sending as intended.  They were sending to the SPAM folder, and I was able to locate them there successfully.